# Downloading a file into Application path

Tags: vb.net

so i am using this code to download file

```
Dim exePath As String = Application.ExecutablePath()
My.Computer.Network.DownloadFile(TextBox2.Text, exePath & "/img.png")
```

where textbox2 contains url to .png file but i get this error
[image]

Note that test.exe is on Desktop.

Comment: `ExecutablePath` is the path of the executable file. If you want the path of the folder that executable is in, you need 'StartupPath`. You should have been able to work that out for yourself by simply reading the documentation.  VS has a Help menu for a reason and you could have just used the F1 key.  ALWAYS read the documentation first.

Comment: Also, use the `Path.Combine` or `My.Computer.FileSystem.CombinePath` method to combine partial paths.  That way, you won't do things like use the wrong slash.

Comment: @ jmcilhinney I am new to this. Can you provide code for path.Combine

Comment: You may be new to programming but you're not new to the web or software in general. VS has a Help menu and you can use a search engine.  Look first, ask questions later.

Comment: Read the words of the error message. What is the name of the file it's telling you it can't create? Does that  look like anything containing `img.png`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it in this way

```
My.Computer.Network.DownloadFile(TextBox2.Text, Environment.CurrentDirectory & "/img.png");
```

**Environment.CurrentDirectory** Will give you the current working directory.

I hope this will work for you.